# Discord.JS V13 client.on messagecreate not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've just recently finished upgrading my Discord.js bot to v13 and now the client.on(messageCreate) function doesn't fire? None of my code in it ever runs and I'm really confused as to why.

Before anybody asks, I have already set my intents.

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [ Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES ],
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], 
});
```

I have two functions, the client.on fires but the message doesn't

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
  console.log(anything)
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code regarding this event?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok i've added in the my events?

Comment: Any errors or runs smoothly?

Comment: It runs smoothly, just no outputs or anything

Comment: @NotTrixxie It runs smoothly, just no outputs or anything

Comment: @NotTrixxie ???

Comment: @NotTrixxie hello?

Comment: The [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have a similar issue. I've noticed that it only fires in a channel if the bot has already sent a message in that channel and not rebooted since.

Comment: For future readers beyond v13: Note that v14 has dramatically changed intents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you include `GUILDS` in your list of intents. Otherwise, the bot can only see messages that have been sent after the bot itself sent a message.

In my case, I needed to set these:

```yaml
partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
intents: ['DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS', 'GUILDS']
```

but the particulars will vary by your use case.

Comment: That wasn't the answer to my problem but after fixing the problem this was needed

Comment: @TonyPatino How did you fix your problem? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @DericLima Unfortunately I don't think this will fix yours but I reinstalled discord.js as I think I had tampered with something that made it not work, make sure though that you do have the partials and intents set like above.

Comment: @TonyPatino No worries, thx anyways. I solved the problem on my end. I misunderstood how bots work in Discord, so I was using events wrongly. All good now

Comment: @DericLima Good to hear